# When CSS link deleted, CSS not working, but when CSS code deleted and saved CSS works

Tags: php, html, css

I'm following a PHP Ecommerce tutorial and for personal reasons I had to stop with the tutorial for a few months and today I got back to it and started off with a video where we are writing CSS code for a sidebar with categories so that it can have a scroll feature on it when more categories are added. I wrote the CSS and it didn't work, I tried watching the tutorial again and everything seems to be fine...then I noticed that if I delete the link for the stylesheet in index.php or any other file the CSS obviously won't work, but when I got into the styles.css file itself and delete all the code, save and refresh the page, the CSS remains on all page's while the CSS code doesn't exist anymore.

Please can anybody help? I will also post any code that you need.

Comment: could be because it's cached by the e-commerce system, so make sure you remove cache

Comment: Are you using a framework? Might be, that the css file you are changing is not the correct css file.

Comment: How can I remove the cache?? Also I am using bootstrap, but the link that I delete the link that is styles/styles.css and when I get into styles.css and delete all the code the css on site works, so I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a default css file that's resetting your styles.css file. Check to make sure there is no other css file that controls the styling (one that acts as the main-stylesheet); simply do an inspect element on whatever div/id you want changed and see the css style that controls it.

Comment: I did, it shows me the correct file and the correct link to it, I have only one folder named styles with styles.css in it, the other folder is named css with styles.css...it shows me the styles folder

Comment: Are using localhost? You need to clear your browser cache. Also unlink the styles.css completely without deleting the code within they stylesheet itself